# Updating a table with more than 850 million rows of data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

I have been tasked with writing an update query to update a table with more than 850 million rows of data. Here are the table structures:

Source Tables :

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SourceTable1](
    [ProdClassID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [PriceListDate] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [PriceListVersion] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [MarketID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ModelID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VariantId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VariantType] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Visibility] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceTable1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [VariantId] ASC,
    [ModelID] ASC,
    [MarketID] ASC,
    [ProdClassID] ASC,
    [PriceListDate] ASC,
    [PriceListVersion] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90)
    )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SourceTable2](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ProdClassID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PriceListDate] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [PriceListVersion] [smallint] NULL,
    [MarketID] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ModelID] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SourceTable2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 91) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

`SourceTable1` contains 52 million rows of data and `SourceTable2` contains 400,000 rows of data.

Here is the `TargetTable` structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TargetTable](
    [ChassisSpecificationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [VariantId] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VariantType] [tinyint] NULL,
    [Visibility] [tinyint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TargetTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ChassisSpecificationId] ASC,
    [VariantId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 71) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The relationship between these tables are as follows:

- `SourceTable1.VariantID` is related to `TargetTable.VariantID`
- `SourceTable2.ID` is related to `TargetTable.ChassisSpecificationId`

The update requirement is as follows:

1. Get the values for `VariantType` and `Visibility` from `SourceTable1` for each `VariantID`, having the maximum value in the `PriceListVersion` column.
2. Get the value of the `ID` column from `SourceTable2` where the values of `ModelID`, `ProdClassID`, `PriceListDate` and `MarketID` match with that of `SourceTable1`.
3. Now update the `TargetTable` with the values for `VariantType` and `Visibility` where the
   `ChassisspecificationID` matches `SourceTable2.ID` and `VariantID` matches `SourceTable1.VariantID`

The challenge is to do this update on live production, with minimum locking. Here is the query I have put together.

```
-- Check if Temp table already exists and drop if it does
IF EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL 
        FROM tempdb.sys.tables
        WHERE name LIKE '#CSpec%'
      )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #CSpec;
END;

-- Create Temp table to assign sequence numbers
CREATE Table #CSpec
(
    RowID int,
    ID uniqueidentifier,
    PriceListDate VarChar(8),
    ProdClassID VarChar(10),
    ModelID VarChar(20),
    MarketID Varchar(10)
 );

-- Populate temp table 
INSERT INTO #CSpec
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MarketID) RowID,
       CS.id, 
       CS.pricelistdate, 
       CS.prodclassid, 
       CS.modelid, 
       CS.marketid 
FROM   dbo.SourceTable2 CS 
WHERE CS.MarketID IS NOT NULL;

-- Declare variables to hold values used for updates
DECLARE @min            int, 
        @max            int,
        @ID             uniqueidentifier,
        @PriceListDate  varchar(8),
        @ProdClassID    varchar(10),
        @ModelID        varchar(20),
        @MarketID       varchar(10);
-- Set minimum and maximum values for looping
SET @min = 1;
SET @max = (SELECT MAX(RowID) From #CSpec);

-- Populate other variables in a loop
WHILE @min <= @max
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @ID = ID,
        @PriceListDate = PriceListDate,
        @ProdClassID = ProdClassID,
        @ModelID = ModelID,
        @MarketID = MarketID
    FROM #CSpec
    WHERE RowID = @min;  

-- Use CTE to get relevant values from SourceTable1 
    ;WITH Variant_CTE AS
    (
    SELECT  V.variantid, 
            V.varianttype, 
            V.visibility,
            MAX(V.PriceListVersion) LatestPriceVersion
    FROM    SourceTable1 V 
    WHERE       V.ModelID = @ModelID
            AND V.ProdClassID = @ProdClassID
            AND V.PriceListDate = @PriceListDate
            AND V.MarketID = @MarketID
    GROUP BY
            V.variantid, 
            V.varianttype, 
            V.visibility
    )

-- Update the TargetTable with the values obtained in the CTE
    UPDATE      SV 
        SET     SV.VariantType = VC.VariantType, 
                SV.Visibility = VC.Visibility
    FROM        spec_variant SV 
    INNER JOIN  TargetTable VC
    ON          SV.VariantId = VC.VariantId
    WHERE       SV.ChassisSpecificationId = @ID
                AND SV.VariantType IS NULL
                AND SV.Visibility IS NULL;

    -- Increment the value of loop variable
    SET @min = @min+1;
END
-- Clean up
DROP TABLE #CSpec
```

It takes about 30 seconds when I set the limit of iterations to 10, by hardcoding the value of `@max` variable. However, when I increase the limit to 50 iterations, then it takes almost 4 minutes to complete. I am concerned that the execution time taken for 400,000 iterations will run into multiple days on production. However, that might still be acceptable, if the `TargetTable` does not get locked down, preventing users from accessing it.

All inputs are welcome.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: 2 people voted for closing this question. Care to explain why?

Comment: People did not vote for closing but for migration to DBA.SE site where there are better chances you get an expert answer.

Comment: Some other things to consider: Stats and Batch updates. See an informative article here on the [MSDN blog SQL Repl](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2011/10/10/lessons-learned-updating-100-millions-rows.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the inputs guys. I was able to tweak the script some more, create relevant indexes and thanks to @Marian's link, I was also able to use multiple sessions in parallel and just completed updating the test DB with 175 million rows in about 40 minutes. That is a giant improvement from the 9.5 hours it was taking my predecessor on the same Test DB. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To speed things up, you could try

- Adding a primary key to #CSpec.RowID so you don't scan it every iteration
- Change the CTE to a temp table with suitable PK. See next point too
- Add an index on SourceTable1 to match the CTE WHERE clause: currently the PK will be scanned, meaning all SourceTable1 rows will be scanned every iteration. All 52 million rows
- SourceTable2.MarketID also does not have an index, but I wouldn't worry about this because it is scanned once only (as I understand it)

The query plans here should show a lot of scans because you have poor indexes for the operations you are doing.

Target table indexing appears OK

Another observation: uniqueidentifier and varchar are bad choices for clustered indexes (your PKs here): too wide, not increasing, overhead of collection comparisons at least

Edit, another observation (thanks to @Marian)

Your clustered index is wide generally. Every non-clustered index points to the clustered index, which means a huge NC index too

You could *probably* achieve the same result by reordering the clustered PK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes sense adding PK to the #CSpec temp table. I decided on using a CTE as each iteration only updates an average of 16 - 20 rows of data. Index on SourceTable1 created. As for your observations for choice of PKs, I agree. Sadly this is inherited and changes to the DB schema may not be possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Posting the final SQL for this process, for the benefit of the community

```
/********************************************************************************************************************
*  Notes: Since this approach executes in a loop inside an explicit transaction, locks will be obtained and         *
*  released for each iteration, thus minimizing impact on other users accessing the same table at the same time.    *
*                                                                                                                   *
*  This process would update 10,000 to 12,000 rows per second, and thus is estimated to run for approximately       *
*  23 hours on production with 850 million rows in Spec_Variant table. However, we can harness the power of         *
*  mutli-threading, by statically defining the @min and @max variable values and then running multiple sessions     *
*  of this update. This will reduce the time required to 23 hours divided by the number of sessions. In other words,* 
*  if we run 8 sessions of this update query parallelly, it should complete in 23/8 ~ 3 hours. If multiple sessions *
*  are possible, then the temp table needs to be created as a global temp table and populated in its own session.   *
*  Additionally, each sessions @max and @min values need to be hard coded,for example, 1-50000, 50001-100000, etc.  *
*********************************************************************************************************************/

-- However, to make this possible, we will have to use...

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;

-- ... this would be the ideal setting to minimize locking. Before using this, we will need to execute
-- ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase
-- SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

-- Alternately, if access rights permit, executing 
-- DBCC TRACEON(1211,-1) will disable lock escalation. Else, the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL can be left at 
-- default (READ COMMITTED), but will not allow us to run multiple sessions.

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Check if Temp table already exists and drop if it does
IF EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL 
        FROM tempdb.sys.tables
        WHERE name LIKE '#CSpec%'
      )
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #CSpec;
END;

-- Create Temp table to assign sequence numbers
CREATE Table #CSpec
    (
    RowID           int PRIMARY KEY,
    ID              uniqueidentifier,
    PriceListDate   VarChar(8),
    ProdClassID     VarChar(10),
    ModelID         VarChar(20),
    MarketID        Varchar(10)
    );

-- Populate temp table 
INSERT INTO #CSpec
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MarketID) RowID,
       CS.id, 
       CS.pricelistdate, 
       CS.prodclassid, 
       CS.modelid, 
       CS.marketid 
FROM   dbo.SourceTable2 CS 
WHERE CS.MarketID IS NOT NULL
-- This AND clause will allow this process to be run multiple times in timed sessions and will prevent
-- an attempt to update rows that were already updated in an earlier session. If the process will be run 
-- only once from start to finish, this block can be commented out
AND CS.Id NOT IN 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT ChassisSpecificationId
                FROM TargetTable
                WHERE VariantType IS NOT NULL AND Visibility IS NOT NULL
            );

-- Declare variables to hold values used for updates
DECLARE @min            int, 
        @max            int,
        @ID             uniqueidentifier,
        @PriceListDate  varchar(8),
        @ProdClassID    varchar(10),
        @ModelID        varchar(20),
        @MarketID       varchar(10);

-- Set minimum and maximum values for looping. See comments in the notes section on top.
SELECT @min = 1,@max = MAX(RowID) From #CSpec;

-- Populate other variables in a loop
WHILE @min <= @max
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SELECT 
        @ID = ID,
        @PriceListDate = PriceListDate,
        @ProdClassID = ProdClassID,
        @ModelID = ModelID,
        @MarketID = MarketID
    FROM #CSpec
    WHERE RowID = @min;  

-- Use CTE to get relevant values from SourceTable1
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT  V.variantid, 
            V.varianttype, 
            V.visibility,
            MAX(V.PriceListVersion) LatestPriceVersion
    FROM    SourceTable1 V 
    WHERE       V.ModelID = @ModelID
            AND V.ProdClassID = @ProdClassID
            AND V.PriceListDate = @PriceListDate
            AND V.MarketID = @MarketID
    GROUP BY
            V.variantid, 
            V.varianttype, 
            V.visibility
    )

-- Update the TargetTable with the values obtained in the CTE
    UPDATE      SV 
    SET         SV.VariantType = VC.VariantType, 
                SV.Visibility = VC.Visibility
    FROM        spec_variant SV 
    INNER JOIN  CTE VC
    ON          SV.VariantId = VC.VariantId
    WHERE       SV.ChassisSpecificationId = @ID
                AND SV.VariantType IS NULL
                AND SV.Visibility IS NULL;

   -- Check for errors and commit transaction
        IF @@ERROR = 0
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
                 -- Increment the value of loop variable
                SET @min = @min+1;
            END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@ERROR <> 0
            BEGIN
                ROLLBACK;
            END
    END CATCH
END
-- Clean up
SET NOCOUNT OFF; 
DROP TABLE #CSpec;
```